# Redirect web pages to a new directory name without using webconfig or htaccess

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex, redirect

We changed a name of a directory from www.oursite.com/**infocus**/pages... to www.oursite.com/**view**/pages...  We are keeping the old one but want to push people to the new url.  How do I rewrite/redirect each page to the new location without using webconfig or htaccess (don't have rights to add or change).  I am using an include statement across all the pages.  I am assuming it would be something with rewrite and regex.

Examples:

> www.oursite.com/infocus/1.aspx  -*goes to*-  www.oursite.com/view/1.aspx
>
> www.oursite.com/infocus/2.aspx  -*goes to*-  www.oursite.com/view/2.aspx
>
> www.oursite.com/infocus/3.aspx  -*goes to*-  www.oursite.com/view/3.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you already accepted an answer, but a preferable way to do this would be a 301 permanent redirect. One easy way would be:

C#

```
<% if (Request.Url.PathAndQuery.StartsWith("/infocus/")) {
       Response.StatusDescription = "Moved Permanently" ;
       Response.StatusCode = 301;
       Response.AddHeader("Location", "http://yourdomain" + Request.Url.PathAndQuery.Replace("/infocus/","/view/"));  
} %>
```

VB

```
<%
    If (Request.Url.PathAndQuery.StartsWith("/infocus/")) Then
        Response.StatusDescription = "Moved Permanently"
        Response.StatusCode = 301
        Response.AddHeader("Location", "http:/yourdomain" + Request.Url.PathAndQuery.Replace("/infocus/", "/view/"))
    End If
%>
```

Can just drop in master page code front. You can do some minor mods to make it a bit more fail-safe and to handle secure/non-secure schema.

Comment: Better solution than mine

Comment: Actually I am getting an error that an end statement is needed.

Compiler Error Message: BC30081: 'If' must end with a matching 'End If'.

Source Error:


Line 1:  <% if (Request.Url.PathAndQuery.StartsWith("/infocus/")) {

Comment: Forgive me as I am not familiar with this code.  I  have a .aspx page that is pulling in a include (also aspx).  When I drop the VB code into the include nothing happens.  The page does not redirect.

Comment: Can I add this just to the include file (header.aspx)?

Comment: I put it inside the include and it does not redirect...  the page loads to the infocus not the redirected page (as seen in the URL).www.../infocus/

Comment: @RooksStrife what is the value of `Request.Url.PathAndQuery` ? I've used this code in many places before and have never had problems with it.

Comment: @RooksStrife You can try changing the `StartsWith` with `Contains`.

Comment: Is there away to change the URL vanity vs. redirect and recreation/renaming of the folder.  So if someone types in:
www.oursite.com/infocus/1.aspx - renames the displayed URL to - www.oursite.com/view/1.aspx and if someone goes to- www.oursite.com/view/2.aspx it the URL displays as www.oursite.com/view/2.aspx but points to www.oursite.com/infocus/2.aspx

Comment: You can't "change" a URL like that. You'll need to redirect. 301 is the proper way as it will also account for search engines.

Comment: That is what I thought, but thought I would give it a try ;]  Thanks for the info and the patience.

Comment: @RooksStrife what language are you using??

Comment: I have a .aspx include file that I am putting your VB code into.

Comment: @RooksStrife well you are showing different errors. The first appeared to be from putting C# in a VB page... the other from putting VB into a C# page. Please ensure you use the correct code for language.

Comment: Got it to work - had to add the '<%@ Page Language="VB" %>'  Now is there a way to make it not display the folder/index.aspx - want it to just be folder/

Comment: @RooksStrife yes. Look into URL Rewriting or FriendlyURLs... and open a new question if you have issues... not adding more comments!

Comment: It's just weird that this aspx method adds the index.aspx as the javascript does not.  i believe we are using Friendly URLS - as normally the index.aspx does not show - only when using the above redirect.

Comment: Because the javascript is running off the URL, which doesn't have index.aspx. PathAndQuery includes the index.aspx whether it shows in the URL or not. You can have a different redirect for index.aspx if you want, though if your site will show both `/view/` and `/view/index.aspx` then you need to look into URL rewriting, as having two URLs for the same page will hurt you from a SEO standpoint (and makes analytics harder).

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<script>
  var loc=location.href;
  if (loc.indexOf("/infocus/")!=-1) 
    location.replace(loc.replace("/infocus/","/view/"));
</script>
```

Comment: @mplungjan this would work, but 301 would be better.

Comment: I agree. I assumed only client solution was available

Comment: @mplungjan perhaps... no details on language was given, but tagged asp.net... so yeah I went there :)